# How can I switch off word wrap for parts of a markdown file in VS Code / VSCodium?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, vscodium, texttable

Is there any way in VSCodium to switch off the line wrapping for a section of a file, in my case a markdown file?

I'm writing as documentation in Markdown and want to include some tables.

Due to the fact that the target system/converter I'm using, which is [mark](https://github.com/kovetskiy/mark), cannot handle manually wrapped cells, I have to stick to one text row being one table row. So for longer cell content, the line length is quickly exceeded and the table becomes an ugly mess of wrapped lines.

Currently I switch off wrapping completely but for the non-table parts, wrapping would be quite handy.

My idea would be to somehow instruct VSCodium to not wrap lines which start with a pipe (`|`), which I have at the beginning of each table row.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know and understand from reading issue tickets, this is not something that is supported at the time of this writing, and I am not aware of any workarounds (though that doesn't mean they don't exist- just that I don't know about them).

There is a feature-request where your problem-scenario is one of the motivators: [Allow line specific word wrap toggling #171457](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171457). You can give it a thumbs up reaction to show support, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress (but please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" or "bump").

I suppose you could also try fiddling with the `markdown.styles` setting and using CSS. Try CSS properties like `overflow`, `overflow-x`, `text-wrap`, `white-space`, etc. Not sure what mileage you'll get for different specific things.

For your reference and learning purposes, the above issue ticket was found by googling "`github vscode markdown issues word wrap tables`".